# How do Windows terminals make Chinese and English characters 1:2 in width?

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal, fonts, text-editors

`ipconfig` output in CMD:

[image]

`ipconfig` output in PowerShell:

[image]

`ipconfig` output in Git Bash:

[image]

Notice the widths of the Chinese and English characters are always 1:2, no matter which font family is used, **and as a result, the dots are aligned**.

I was amazed by this, since in an ordinary text editor, VSCode for example, the output will look like this (font family is Consolas, which is monospaced):

[image]

As you can see, **the dots are not aligned**, and unlike the terminals listed above, you'd have to find some special font families (e.g. [Sarasa Gothic](https://github.com/be5invis/Sarasa-Gothic)) to make the width ratio 1:2.

So, my question is, **how do these Windows terminals make Chinese and English characters 1:2 in width regardless of the font family? And can we achieve that in text editors?**

Comment: that alignment difference is - for me, at least - almost always caused by the difference between mono-spaced and proportional fonts. have you checked that?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey The font family in the above VSCode screenshot is Consolas (monospaced).

Comment: ah! thank you for the clarification! that removes one idea ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This conversation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/47983) explains it all:

[image]

P.S. Although "Inconsolata" is a great font to solve this alignment issue, but I found the English characters of this font are a bit too slim for me, so I'm currently still using "Consolas".

Answer (score 1):

> how do these Windows terminals make Chinese and English characters 1:2 in width regardless of the font family?

Most coding-style terminals or code-text-editors display characters in a literal X/Y grid, and ignore font for spacing entirely. However, most "general" text-editors only use the glyph width defined in the font to determine where to place the next character.

> Can we achieve that in text editors?

Obviously, features depend on the editor itself, but **Monospaced** fonts are used to align characters in any text editor. For example, VS Code uses monospaced fonts by default (Settings > Text editor > Fonts), so it is usually aligned properly.

Not all monospaced fonts are equal though, and uncommon or Wide characters can be exceptions in fonts that you would normally expect to be monospaced like [Consolas](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/47983). You can try a font that renders wide characters as 2 latin characters instead e.g. Inconsolata.

Ligatures (joined-characters) may also be enabled in the editor, and you can run into monospaced fonts without monospaced ligature glyphs.